# Creating imaps in vim that don't cause to much of a delay

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm working on a little vim plugin for a new language. I'm currently working on some cool effects to change some characters and words into badass unicode character such as `\` turns into `λ`.

I now want to make `not` turn into `¬` but this causes some complications since I cant just match on `not` since that would cause a word like `nottingham` to turn into `¬tingham` so I created the imap:

```
inoremap <space>not<space> ¬
```

But this causes an annoying delay every time space is pressed. Is there anyway to fix this?

**NOTE:**
I'm not using `conceal` since it causes the characters to flip back and fourth and it messes with the highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an abbreviation for this:

```
:abbrev not ¬
```

For the "space before 'not' part":
from `:help abbreviations` ('not' is a `full-id` abbreviation, see the help for all abbreviation types):

```
The characters before the cursor must match the abbreviation.  Each type has
an additional rule:

full-id   In front of the match is a non-keyword character, or this is where
          the line or insertion starts.  Exception: When the abbreviation is
          only one character, it is not recognized if there is a non-keyword
          character in front of it, other than a space or a tab.
```

For the "space after 'not' part":

```
An abbreviation is only recognized when you type a non-keyword character.
This can also be the <Esc> that ends insert mode or the <CR> that ends a
command.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
iabbrev not ¬
```

This uses the built-in abbreviation system which is much faster
than inoremap with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified and default behaviour is timeout delay is controlled by `timeoutlen=1000` when `timeout` is `on`, default value is `on`.

So, to reduce to half the current timeout value, `:set timeoutlen=500`.

More at `:h timeout`.
Not sure, if this is what you are looking but is more flexible than `abbr` approach.

Comment: I used `abbrev` but thanks anyway! Setting the timeout to a lower value is still really nice!

Do you know if its possible to set different timeouts for normal mode and insert mode ?

Comment: Sure, But I will prefer `timeout` way . For example, try typing `This is not vi but vim`. You will always end up `abbr` expanded. Nope, `timeout` is common to both mode, `normal` as well as `insert`